# How to show ACF relationship field elements in Elementor Pro posts widget?

Tags: relationship, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I am creating an encyclopedia section of a website built with Elementor Pro. I've used ACF to create a custom post type called "Encyclopedia". Each encyclopedia post has an ACF relationship field called "related_topics" which is filled with related topics and returns Post IDs. I have added the following code to my functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/related_topics_query', function( $query ) { 
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' ); 
    $meta_query[] = [ 
        'key' => 'related_topics', // ACF relationship field name 
        'value' => get_the_ID(), 
        'compare' => '=', 
    ]; 
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query ); 
} );
```

I have put "related_topics_query" in the Query ID field of an Elementor Posts widget, but the widget shows the standard posts from other parts of the website, not the ACF related posts from the Encyclopedia custom post type. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

=============

I found the solution. I am using a child theme and needed to put the php into the functions.php file of the child theme instead of using a plugin to load the php. Here is where I found the solution:  https://mainetcare.de/en/techdoc/elementor-works-widget-with-acf-relationship-fill/